# Finding Line Spacings in Thresholded Image - R/C++ Image Processing

Tags: c++, r, image, image-processing

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I have a question about **Image Processing**. I will give a short introduction about my project, clear things up and ask my question.

> I use R now, with EBImage library. After that I will write that code on C++.

In material analysis, the microstructural analysis are done in sake of understanding the structure of steel. It gives some hints to the analyzer.

**My duty is; finding the line spacings in the image. I will explain it by images.**

> Image is taken from: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlit_(Stahl)

I will post a collage image, because I cannot upload images more than 2. 
**First photo** is the image of perlit microstructure. **Second photo** is thresholded image after preprocessing. **Third photo** is what I made on Paint to show you the regions that I need to find.

2. Photo, "Pre-processing" is done by doing:

   - Grayscaling the Image.
   - Closing Filter by 7x7 Gaussian Kernel
   - Dilating Filter by 3x3 Box Kernel
   - Median Filter 7x7
   - Thresholding Image

Black and White image in collage photo is the result of these steps.

[Collage Photo of Perlit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK0vd.jpg)

Now, if you look this image, there are some line spacings shown by red pencil via Paint, in the 3rd photo. I want to make a segmentation to show them painted.

You can clearly see that I got rid of tiny vertical lines, made clear segments.

**I need help in segmentation.** I am currently reading lots of computer vision and image processing books, but unfortunately I couldn't find a good solution. In EBImage, there are some functions but "bwlabel" or "watershed" didn't help me a lot.

> The segmentation will be done in this image horizontally. But there would be an image with gradiental line spacings.

I am not asking this question for ready copy-paste answers. I really want to learn how to do this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for reading my questions.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a horizontal pattern in the structure.. is it always like this? Have you tried exploiting this correlation? Maybe extract [vertical histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF1Jg.jpg) (histogram over rows of pixels), and find maximas?

I reread your question, already saw that you are taking into account the horizontality. Knowing this, if you just want to paint the red regions, then you already have a good binary mask to paint them.. or you dont want to paint the small white patches between the dark structure?

Cheers

Comment: No, it can be also gradiental, not always horizontal or vertical.

Comment: I want to paint the long line spacings in the image. I have a good binary mask but I want to eliminate little areas. Line spacings should be longer ones.

Comment: you could rotate the image analizing the general direction of the patterns? frequency analysis or hough transform?

Comment: a bit of a long shot, but you could use Stroke Width Transformation http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf to analyze the white segments in your image. If they are elongated and have a given width, then its the segment you want

Comment: I need some time to analyse your advices and of course I should implement them in R. Then I will write the results here.

Thank you very much for your advices.